# Creating a class namespace from a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way I can compose a class namespace from a variable?

For example, let's say I want to catch an exception that is inside `Foo::Bar::MyException`, but `Bar` is in a variable (`a = :Bar`).

Would that be something like `Foo::@a::MyException`?

Comment: Can you provide an example? It's hard to understand what you're asking for just from the question alone.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this

```
Foo.const_get(@a)::MyException
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can:

```
module A
  module B
    class C
      def foo
        "bar"
      end
    end
  end
end

variable = "B"
c_instance = Object.const_get("A::#{variable}::C").new
puts c_instance.foo
```